# Qt Stylesheet button background color

Tags: c++, qt, qtstylesheets

I'm using a style sheet to set the background color of a QPushbutton:

```
QPushButton {
     background-color: red;
     border-style: outset;
     border-width: 2px;
     border-color: beige;
}
```

This is working but when I change the background-color of QWidget as well, the button has the same background-color as the QWidget (in this example the button is black instead of red).

```
QWidget {
    background-color: black;
}
```

Does anyone knows how to get the button colored when setting the background-color of the QWidget?

Comment: you could name your widget and change the stylesheet to QWidget#name {...} this should only affect the widget that has that name.

Comment: Note order matters. These issues (almost this exact one in fact) are discussed [here.](http://doc.qt.digia.com/4.7-snapshot/stylesheet-syntax.html#conflict-resolution)

Answer (score 1):

I don't exactly know why this is happening, but putting the button's stylesheet along with the widgets stylesheet will bring the effect you want. For example, in your case, the **widget's stylesheet** will be as follows

```
QWidget 
{
    background-color: black;
}

QPushButton
{
    background-color: red;
    border-style: outset;
    border-width: 2px;
    border-color: beige;
}
```

Hope this helps!! Good Luck! :D